# How to join empty to mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm not sure how to explain this so forgive me for not not being able to explain it correctly, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to join the empty I've made with a different mesh of mine?

[image]

I need the cylinder that I made with the empty to be joined with my s4studio mesh, but any time that I try to join them it ends up looking like this (left is whole mesh, right is after I joined it):

[image]

I hope I'm making sense here! I've tried searching for this question many different ways and haven't been able to find answer to help me, but if I missed one on here I apologize for the inconvenience!

Comment: I think it would help if you explained why you want to join your empty to the mesh. You can't, but if we understood your reasoning we could potentially figure out how to help. It looks like you're using the empty to drive an object offset array. What more are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Rekov Yes, so sorry, I'm using the array modifier to create the many rounded cylinders. The reason why I need them together is because I'm making an object for a game (The Sims 4) and I'm uploading it into a program that will only read the one mesh and not anything else. So it has to be together somehow because atm it's only showing the top and bottom portion in the program I have to use. I hope this makes sense! This is the only thing left I need to do for this. The object needs to be low poly so that is why I'm using the array modifier.

Comment: Gotcha. The array modifier is creating polygons. All it does is take your existing mesh and duplicate it depending on how you've set up the modifier. If you want to join up your various objects, you'll have to apply that array modifier first. The polys are there regardless of whether the modifier is applied or not, if you manually duplicated that element around. If that's too high poly, your best bet would be to have a simple cylinder as your mesh, and bake the bumpy surface onto the normal map.

Comment: @Rekov So sorry for this super late response! I was so dumb and didn't realize that I didn't apply the modifier first and that's what really stopped me form moving forward. Thank you for the help!